# How to upload a file together with a json of an object containing additional information about the file?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

please how to upload a CSV file (product catalog) together with a JSON of object containing name and datesof the catalog? I'm using Spring Boot (1.3.3.RELEASE) with jackson-databind for JSON REST API and SwaggerUI (2.1.4 - included directly in the project, not as a Maven dependency). I created following endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Create catalogue by uploading a file", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Catalogue createCatalogue(@RequestPart("catalogue") Catalogue catalogue, MultipartFile file) {...}
```

DTO Catalogue looks like this:

```
@Data
public class Catalogue {
    private String name;
    private LocalDate validFrom;
    private LocalDate validTo;
}
```

I use SwaggerUI to post a file and a json (textarea) to this endpoint:

```
{"name":"Katalog 2016"}
```

But I'm getting error when Spring tries to deserialize Catalogue because contentType is null:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
```

This is the full request as it is logged by the logging filter:

```
REQUEST: {"method":"POST","path":"/api/v1/catalogues","params":{"catalogue":"{\"name\":\"Katalog 2016\"}"},"headers":{"content-length":"318","referer":"http://localhost:8000/swagger/index.html","accept-language":"cs","cookie":"oracle.uix=0^^GMT+1:00^p; wp-settings-time-1=1458506367; pll_language=en; 9d4bb4a09f511681369671a08beff228=9kp8k4p5rtbsvb0dtg0c585l50; 462bddfc0804b9e2d3bedb862fe829b3=jg9rhnasq47dnluai04pp9dpg0; 6b983e6bbfb12fe47cd501a09aa63a2f=t4bg8eeakngjag7pkd3qldjki1; wp-settings-2=editor%3Dhtml%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse; wp-settings-time-2=1459108118; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_86a9106ae65537651a8e456835b316ab=admin%7C1459353525%7ChXEWYSjH45ohapLSXw6NZOyIdQ0qrDGpSDieVRbNCh1%7Cd39d1b99843b348cca8c992a3908ae6aef303e9e7196d38fa6173fd91146b260; JSESSIONID=93D946F7EC2F8E8FFC880A1D5752BBEA","origin":"http://localhost:8000","host":"localhost:8000","x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest","connection":"keep-alive","content-type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMnZeiNwIgldJlGGd","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","accept":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"},"body":[EMPTY]}
```

Please what am I missing? Many thanks in advance. Vojtech

**UPDATE:**
I introduced CommonsMultipartResolver:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(5242880L);
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

And I'm getting another error now:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'catalogue' is not present
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your endpoint in catalogue part.
Annotation `@RequestPart` is for files not for objects.
Probably you need this endpoint definition:

```
public Catalogue createCatalogue(@RequestParam("catalogue") String catalogue, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
}
```